# unable to get trade data using @sushiswap/core-sdk

Tags: nodejs, sushiswap

I am trying to get trade information based on user provided information, but code is failing at building `Trade`.

here is code

```
const sellAssetValue = {
    decimal: 18,
    symbol: 'ETH',
}
const buyAssetValue = {
    decimal: 18,
    symbol: 'USDC',
}

// WETH
const sellAssetAddress = "0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2"
// USDC
const buyAssetAddress = "0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48";

console.log(sellAssetAddress, buyAssetAddress)

const tokenA = new SushiSwapToken(1, sellAssetAddress as string, sellAssetValue.decimal ?? 18, sellAssetValue.symbol);
const tokenB = new SushiSwapToken(1, buyAssetAddress as string, sellAssetValue.decimal ?? 18, sellAssetValue.symbol);


const tokenACurrencyAmount = CurrencyAmount.fromRawAmount(tokenA, 1000000000000000000);
const tokenBCurrencyAmount = CurrencyAmount.fromRawAmount(tokenB, 0);

const pair = new Pair(tokenACurrencyAmount, tokenBCurrencyAmount);

const route = new Route([pair], tokenA, tokenB)

const trade = new Trade(route, tokenACurrencyAmount, TradeType.EXACT_INPUT);
console.log(trade.outputAmount.toFixed(buyAssetValue.decimal ?? 18))
```

here here is error

```
error: InsufficientReservesError
      at _construct (/Users/abc/project/node_modules/@sushiswap/core-sdk/dist/core-sdk.cjs.development.js:226:10)
      at Wrapper (/Users/abc/project/node_modules/@sushiswap/core-sdk/dist/core-sdk.cjs.development.js:250:14)
      at new InsufficientReservesError (/Users/abc/project/node_modules/@sushiswap/core-sdk/dist/core-sdk.cjs.development.js:925:13)
      at getOutputAmount (/Users/abc/project/node_modules/@sushiswap/core-sdk/dist/core-sdk.cjs.development.js:1456:13)
      at new Trade (/Users/abc/project/node_modules/@sushiswap/core-sdk/dist/core-sdk.cjs.development.js:1833:37)
      at /Users/abc/project/data-layer/providers/src/sushiswapv2/index.ts:113:17
      at fetchQuote (/Users/abc/project/data-layer/providers/src/sushiswapv2/index.ts:54:29)
      at /Users/abc/project/data-layer/providers/src/sushiswapv2/index.test.ts:16:23
      at /Users/abc/project/data-layer/providers/src/sushiswapv2/index.test.ts:7:45
```

Answer (score 0):

The error: InsufficientReservesError happens because the pair has insufficient reserves for a desired output amount. i.e., the amount of output cannot be
obtained by sending any amount of input. You can refer to the SDK repo for more information and condition of raising this error at https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-sdk/blob/main/src/errors.ts#L8.

For your code, you have a small typos at const tokenB. It should be **BuyAssetValue.decimal ?? 18, BuyAssetValue.symbol** not the **sellAsset** because you already use it in tokenA. Fix the code to the following should fix your problem

```
const tokenA = new SushiSwapToken(1, sellAssetAddress as string, sellAssetValue.decimal ?? 18, sellAssetValue.symbol);
const tokenB = new SushiSwapToken(1, buyAssetAddress as string, BuyAssetValue.decimal ?? 18, BuyAssetValue.symbol);
```

Hope it helps.